# Two Users in Docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, alpine-linux

I am trying to use two users with Docker for my Spring Boot application running in an OpenJDK/Alpine base image.

Here is my scenario that I am trying to support. Maybe there is a better way.

> I need to provide production support so I want to attach with EXEC as
>   `devuser:appgroup` but I am not allowed by our security
>   department to see credentials or secrets so the application should RUN
>   as `appuser:appgroup` which would also own all the application files.

I can build the image with the correct(?) permissions.

```
/opt/app $ ls -l
total 24552
-r-sr-xr-x    1 appuser  appgroup     10632 Jun 27 12:59 app
-r--------    1 appuser  appgroup  25101769 Jun 27 12:59 app.jar
-r-xr-xr--    1 appuser  appgroup       327 Jun 27 12:59 app.sh
-r--------    1 appuser  appgroup       316 Jun 27 12:59 application.yml
-r-sr-xr-x    1 root     root         10632 Jun 27 12:59 setup
-r-xr-xr--    1 root     root           152 Jun 27 12:59 setup.sh
```

The application runs well when I specify USER `appuser` but when I connect to the running container using EXEC I am `appuser` and I can see the configuration.

The application does not run when I specify USER `devuser` but when I connect to the running container using EXEC I am blocked from viewing the as I should be.

As you can see from the file permissions I am trying SUID but that seems somewhat of a hack to write a C program to run a shell script and is not working for me. (The last part is probably lack of experience on my part.)

I would appreciate any help,
Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to disable exec for the user running the inside the container. Find another way to hide configuration.

Comment: I am not looking to disable EXEC because we will probably need to use it if the application is not running as expected and looking at the log files does not reveal the issue.
I posted this question looking for ideas on ways to hide the credentials. If I were not using Docker I would use two separate users. This is kind of if all you have is a hammer then everything looks like a nail situation. I am hoping that someone else has found a way to solve this. I seems odd that no one else has the same issue.